# Why does the arc stop few seconds of running?

Tags: high-voltage, flyback, electronic-ballast

I am running a CRT Flyback transformer using a 36W/40W Philips Ballast. My primary winding is of 20 turns. I do get a nice arc. But it stops after a few seconds. To strike the arc again I have to switch off the Ballast for a few seconds and switch it on again.

Comment: There's no way anyone can help without a schematic. Show us details of what you're doing.

Comment: Where is the voltage to "maintain" arcing?

Comment: I will take a SWAG: You are probably overloading it and causing it to saturate and or the power supply is collapsing. Follow up with Hearth's request for a schematic and technical information on the parts or links to that.

Comment: The secondary of a CRT flyback transformer is **very** fine wire. The current of a visible arc would be a serious overload for this type of wire, and it is probably self-heating to the point where its resistance is too high to sustain the arc. If you want continuous visible arcs, you need something more like a NST (neon sign transformer).

Comment: your ballast is designed to run fluorescent lights, it sees the flybac trasfromer as some sort of fault, and so, switches off.

Comment: Thanks Jasen, I too think that is the problem.  Just noticed that the ballast has an auto shutdown feature. Also this is an instant start ballast (I'm assuming). It gives out around ~600v to start the CFL. The arc keeps going for a few seconds cause the air is ionised. Then the voltage drops and an the air is also ionised no more. Hence the arc stops.